# PHP get value disappears

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an html form that is filled with the values I get from a MySQL Database query. The query is by an `id` that is sent via GET.

I send the id to the form along with a button that is surrounded by an anchor `<a>`:

`<a href='editRQS.php?id=$row[0]'><button class='edit'>Edit</button></a>`

`$row[0]` is filled by the proper `id` and I'm sure it's working ok. When I click the button the url is sent carrying the `id`. It is then received at the other page like this:

```
<?php
$id = -1;

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo "<label class='exists' id='idRequest'> $id</label>";       
}

if($id != -1 ){
    echo '<form id="findRequest" class="hide" >';
} else {
    echo '<form id="findRequest" class="show" >';
}   
?>
```

The problem is that the `id` arrives at the page - but then it disappears. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

The page seems to reload, i have no idea why, i have some javascript that manages some of the page functionality and the only thing that could cause this is an event handler for when the another form is submitted but I have prevented it like this:

```
$('anotherForm').on('submit',function(e){
   .
   .
   .
   e.preventDefault();
 }
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to everybody that helped, i have yet to find the reason it doesn't work, i tried dissabling javascript and the page stoped reloading so i guess it's another thing that's messing my page up

Comment: What do you mean by it arrives at the page but then it disappears?

Comment: When you click the button, are you arriving at the URL as expected? In this case, does the URL look like `editRQS.php?id=XX` when the button is clicked? Is the `<button>` nested inside a `<form>` tag? If so, it might just be sending all of the form information to the script instead of the actual href from the `<a>` tag.

Comment: what are you seeing as output?  What did you expect to see?  Is this the only code that touches `$id`?  What do you mean by "disappears"?

Comment: what do you mean when you say disappears?

Comment: Did you try to echo $id in the first `if` block? (where you are assigning $_GET['id']    )

Comment: What do you mean it arrives at the page but then disappears? Do you mean the id is there on initial page load but then disappears when you refresh the page?

Comment: I have echoed the value to the page and it appears but then it doesn't.

Comment: @sbeliv01 Yes the URL is sent like that

Comment: @orzechowskid I expected to have the form echoed with the class of hide, instead it appears with a class of show

Comment: Normally a rendered page doesn't change. When you say it 'appears', where does it appear? And in what manner does it appear? When you say it disappears, are there any intermediate actions that are taken?

Comment: @NathanielFord I tried echoing it and it echoes "13" for example, but then the page seems to reload and it echoes a -1;

Comment: Do the page reload when `Edit` button is clicked? You said _it echoed `13` and then page got reloaded_

Comment: Try this: just create a totally brand new, blank page called, say, `test.php`. In it, put simply `foo: <?php echo $_GET['foo'] ?>`. Then go to `test.php?foo=bar`. What happens?

Comment: @Davinder the `Edit` button it's in another page, i get to the one that has the PHP code via the anchor tag

Comment: If doing what I suggested works, then just add to `test.php`, little by little, until you get what you were originally after. And if at some point during that process it stops working, you'll know exactly what little change made it stop working.

Comment: @IsaacGonzalez echo $_GET['foo']; should simply echo `bar`, not `foo: bar`

Comment: @Davinder i added `foo:` before the php code, so i guess it should appear

Comment: Isaac is right, and that output is correct. Now, Isaac, change `test.php?foo=bar` to `test.php?id=13`, and change every `foo` to `id` instead. Maybe add some of your HTML output from the original code. You know, add things in, little by little. See if it keeps working or not.

Comment: If you don't want to do what I suggested, here's another suggestion: delete all the JavaScript on the original page, then test again. Has the problem gone away? If so, something in the JavaScript is the problem. If not, something else is the problem. Delete (or comment out) more code and then test again.

Comment: @JasonSwett changed everything `foo` to `id` i'm going to rebuild the page to see where it stopped working, Thanks a lot man

Comment: @JasonSwett Yeah men it's my javascript that's not working, how can i give you some more rep or something for helping ?

Comment: I'm not too worried about it. If you want, you could upvote my comments, although I don't know if that affects rep or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is reloading because the form gets submitted. It isn't enough to `preventDefault` the form submission. Try `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` the latter preventing form submission when a submit button is clicked (clicks are still handled, and, in some cases propagate to the form, that is then submitted.

Also, I see you're using jQuery. Just let your event handler return false. jQuery automatically converts a false-returning handler to a `e.preventDefault() ||e.returnValue = false e.stopPropagation() || e.cancelBubble = true;` construction. Or you could write the code yourself...?

Answer (score 0):

Check your register_globals setting, if it is on you will be overriding $_GET['id'] with the first statement.

You can easily check it by renaming $id to something other then $id.

Comment: Activating `register_globals` does not override, hide or disable any of the superglobals (like $_GET).